# List items manipulation Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, list

Let's say I got the following list:

```
 lst =  ['D 16', 'E 32', 'C 5555', 'C 1', 'B 323']
```

I am trying to create a function that turns `lst` into:

```
lst = ['D', '16', 'E', '32', 'C', '5555', 'C', '1', 'B', '323']
```

I can't however generalise this application, any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lst2=[]
for i in lst:
   lst2.extend(i.split())
```

Or using list comprehension

```
lst=[j for i in lst for j in i.split()]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a generator like this:

```
def generate_parts(l):
    for item in l:
        for part in l.split():
            yield part

lst2 = list(generate_parts(my_list))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def newList(l):
    ret = []
    # Iterate over all elements
    for i in l:
        # Split current string by space into a list 
        # Appened list to ret
        ret += i.split()
    return ret


lst = ['D 16', 'E 32', 'C 5555', 'C 1', 'B 323']
print(newList(lst))
```

Outputs:

```
['D', '16', 'E', '32', 'C', '5555', 'C', '1', 'B', '323']
```